# C# date formatting results in previous day

Tags: c#-4.0, datetime-format

Here's the C# code:

```
employee.BirthDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

While running the unit test on my computer with BirthDate = "1/1/1981" that comes from the SQL Server database, the above code results in "1981-01-01". But, while running the same code on the QA server, it  results in "1980-12-31".

I tried doing the following:

```
employee.BirthDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
employee.Birthdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

But both these lines of code result in the same "1980-12-31" on the QA server.

What could be possibly causing this and what is a solution?

NOTE: The clock on my computer and the QA server are in sync. Also, I checked the .NET globalization in IIS on QA server, where the code is running, and the culture is set to "Invariant".

Comment: Where are you displaying the date? It sounds like it has to do with time zones and that the q/a server might be on a different time zone than whatever is displaying the date (browser?). To avoid this pit fall transfer all dates and datetimes as UTC. When applicable convert them to local time zone at the last possible moment (presentation layer).

Comment: Again, where are you displaying the date? How are you validating the results are different?

Comment: It's not going to any presentation layer on any screen. The birth date is passed in an API call, which is failing due to incorrect date in the API request.

Comment: API can mean almost anything. Define API. Are you passing this value through a asp.net web-api controller? PCOM? COM Interop? A .net library that can be consumed?....

Comment: It's a 3rd party RESTful API. It doesn't matter though because the same API call on my computer works with the same underlying data in database.

Comment: You have to consider the DateTimeKind set on the instance in conjunction with how the date is serialized/deserialized. A value of `Local` being serialized to an api that expects UTC could adjust the date by XX hours (depending on the target timezone). The inverse is also true, UTC sent to the API but displays/uses local so adjusts the date to Local. This has nothing to do with Invariant Culture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code did the trick:

```
employee.BirthDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure it's not a timezone/daylight savings issue.

It might be returning something without the right timezone set, resulting in subtracting a few hours and rolling you into the previous day.